# Unable to pin Edge to taskbar

Tags: modern-ui, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I've had the quite the ordeal with Windows 10...

Is there a way to pin Edge to the taskbar/start menu? I'm able to run it from Run > `microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com`, but it doesn't give me any task bar buttons. Cortona doesn't even have it in her index.

Edit: it works under a different user account (which is a pain to create without a Microsoft account). I don't want to give up on this profile.

Comment: Something must be wrong, by default Edge is pinned to both the taskbar and the start menu and it has the pin command in its context menu. Can you try a different user on the same machine?

Comment: I cheched recently: Microsoft Edge opens like other apps, appears in the task bar and can be pined in the ordinal way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a powershell command to run that reinitializes the app database:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Source: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-apps-re-register-windows-8-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

Edge was pinned to the taskbar after installation, but after some event, which I can't determine, Edge was no longer pinned to the task nor does it show up in start -> all apps.  I went to c:windows/systemApps/microsoft.microsoftedge... and searched for MicrosoftEdge.exe.  After right clicking and sending to desktop, I was able to drag the desktop icon to the taskbar.  I was also able to pin to start although it still does not show up in all apps under Microsoft.